# How to get child of child value from firebase in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How to get ZNAME value? Initially i need to compare key(Ex::Here ZONE_1) and then ZNAME need to be get. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Any code to show so far? Use can simply call `child()` twice on any Database reference

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To access a value in your database, you create a `DatabaseReference` for that location. Here are three references to locations in your database:

```
DatabaseReference zonesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ZONES");
DatabaseReference zone1Ref = zonesRef.child("ZONE_1");
DatabaseReference zone1NameRef = zone1Ref.child("ZNAME");
```

In this snippet:

- `zonesRef` points to `/ZONES`
- `zone1Ref` points to `/ZONES/ZONE_1`
- `zone1NameRef` points to `/ZONES/ZONE_1/ZNAME`

See the [Firebase documentation on getting a database reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#get_a_databasereference) for more information.

You can attach a listener to each of the references, to get the value at that location. For example, to get the value of the `/ZONES/ZONE_1/ZNAME`:

```
zone1NameRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i(TAG, dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

For more on this type of read operation, see the [Firebase documentation on reading values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events).

If you instead listen on `/ZONES/ZONE_1`, you will get a `DataSnapshot` of the entire node with all its properties. You then use `DataSnapshot.child()` to get the `ZNAME` from it:

```
zone1Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i(TAG, dataSnapshot.child("ZNAME").getValue(String.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

One more level up, you can listen on `/ZONES`, which will get you a snapshot with all the zones. Since this handles multiple children, you will need to loop through them with `DataSnapshot.getChildren()`:

```
zonesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot zoneSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i(TAG, zoneSnapshot.child("ZNAME").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

For more on this, see the [Firebase documentation on listening for lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).

Finally, you might want to query to find a specific zone, for example to find the zone with `"ZCODE": "ECOR"`:

```
Query zonesQuery = zonesRef.orderByChild("ZCODE").equalTo("ECOR");
zonesQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot zoneSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i(TAG, zoneSnapshot.child("ZNAME").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

To learn more about this, read the [Firebase documentation on sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: Very simple and clear explanation. Keep up good work with firebase api exploration!!!

Comment: FVP to the rescue once again!

Comment: Good explanation!
Without knowing branch child(here:ZONE_1), is that possible get directly the value of ZNAME for each zones?

Answer (score 2):

**EASIER METHOD!!**

If you want to access the values "Z_Name" of all the child nodes of "Zones" then you can do so using the following code.

```
    final DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Zones");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    String z_name=snapshot.child("Z_name").getValue().toString();
    
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

`
the required value is stored in(this line is already present in above code) :

```
String z_name=snapshot.child("Z_name").getValue().toString();
```

this variable **"z_name"** will have the value of Zone_1 in the first iteration of for loop and the value of Zone_2 in the second iteration of for loop respectively.

Extra: If there had been nodes further we could have used `datasnapshot.getChildren()` again to access it's child nodes