# Getting child values in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure

```
root
  -class1
     -section1
        -student1
            -firstname
            -lastname
        -student2
            -firstname
            -lastname
     -section2
        -student1
            -firstname
            -lastname
        -student2
            -firstname
            -lastname
```

I need to get the section number **(Section1, section2...)** and for every section, the lastname for student2. 
The problem that i facing is that it is all in a Fragment class in android that I need to display and nothing seems to be working. I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293935/how-to-get-child-of-child-value-from-firebase-in-android) for getting the children too, but the for loop somehow does not work and I get **Null** values on retrieval.

I need to get

```
section1, lastname (of student2 in section1)
section2, lastname (of student2 in section2)
...
and so on until all sections are exhausted
```

Answer (score 0):

U can make a model class like

```
class Class{
Arrylist<section> sections;
};

class section{
Arrylist<Student> students;
};

class Student{
String firstname, lastname;
};
```

then get the value of classes

have other way, without making many model classes, but that is more painful and time consuming . If u want that feel free to comment.

Comment: I would like to take a look at that as well. Thank you

Comment: get the value in Object class.

HashMap<String, Object> data= (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

then break the object into your desirable value.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference classRef = rootRef.child("class1");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String lastname = ds.child("student2").child("lastname").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", lastname);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
classRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```