# firebase accessing child and grandchild nodes android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

solved

[Android - Firebase - Getting Child of Child Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382925/android-firebase-getting-child-of-child-data)

how to view leaf nodes both children and grandchildren

E/data: {6640={first={sub3=dbms, m5=3, m2=2, sub2=dl, sub1=cis, m3=2, sub4=socio, m4=2, sub5=english, m1=4}}}

[firebase data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pje5o.jpg)

the values i want are

1. the children inside 6640 eg : first and second
2. the grandchildren inside first eg : sub1--sub5 and m1-m5

the data above is a snapshot data snapshot from a query.. how do i access each values from the following snapshot.. i created a data module and used a for each loop like this

```
 for (DataSnapshot post : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
     {
      trial_module m2 = post.getValue(trial_module.class);
      Log.e("data",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
      data2.add(m2);
      }
```

do i need to create mutiple classes to hold data?

```
public class Result_module {
    String sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4,sub5;
    long m1,m2,m3,m4,m5;


    public String getSub1() {
        return sub1;
    }

    public void setSub1(String sub1) {
        this.sub1 = sub1;
    }

    public String getSub2() {
        return sub2;
    }

    public void setSub2(String sub2) {
        this.sub2 = sub2;
    }

    public String getSub3() {
        return sub3;
    }

    public void setSub3(String sub3) {
        this.sub3 = sub3;
    }

    public String getSub4() {
        return sub4;
    }

    public void setSub4(String sub4) {
        this.sub4 = sub4;
    }

    public String getSub5() {
        return sub5;
    }

    public void setSub5(String sub5) {
        this.sub5 = sub5;
    }

    public long getM1() {
        return m1;
    }

    public void setM1(long m1) {
        this.m1 = m1;
    }

    public long getM2() {
        return m2;
    }

    public void setM2(long m2) {
        this.m2 = m2;
    }

    public long getM3() {
        return m3;
    }

    public void setM3(long m3) {
        this.m3 = m3;
    }

    public long getM4() {
        return m4;
    }

    public void setM4(long m4) {
        this.m4 = m4;
    }

    public long getM5() {
        return m5;
    }

    public void setM5(long m5) {
        this.m5 = m5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your `trial_module` class

Comment: Please add a more detailed database structure and show us the exact values that you want to get.