# Firebase retrieve all child values and displayed

Tags: android, firebase

Firebase android: how to retrieve all users contact and show them using recyclerview ? help me please. thank you in advance.

[my database screenshot](https://www.mediafire.com/view/h1spcyuzr401jnc)

Comment: Possible duplicate please try googling before asking here in community thanks. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293935/how-to-get-child-of-child-value-from-firebase-in-android

Comment: No... Look at the image of my database. I want to select child who have different parents

Comment: Thumbs up, btw Ill make a solution just wait for the answer

Comment: For future reference, it’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your database structure

Your database structure is kind a broken but you can try this

```
Users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
Contacts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

Users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for(DataSnapshot userKeys:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
              //get All the users
              final String users = userKeys.getKey();
              //get contacts
              Contacts.child(users).child("contact").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                      for(DataSnapshot contacts:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                          String contact = contacts.getValue(String.class);
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),contact+"of"+users,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                  }
              });
              //end of get contact
          }
          //End of for each
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
  });
```

Comment: your welcome, Just accept my answer if you want so.

Comment: Please... how to display the list of contacts that I  retrieved using recyclerview

Comment: Actually it will be a long convo when we continue this but search it on youtube for tutorials it would be easy to understand.